# Understanding contraction in hyperplane arrangements.

Tags: projective-geometry, lattice-orders, affine-geometry, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

Here are two figures that shows a hyperplane arrangement's contraction (this is from McNulty book, "Matroids, a geometric introduction"):

> [image]
> [image]

I am not sure why a became a line in the right figure of 7.19, can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Why don't you give the title and author(s) of the corresponding book ?

Comment: You'll need to consult the text you got this from for the language. But both arrangements in 7.19 come from 7.18 and then doing something to line a in 7.18. The A' comes from just deleting line a, and A'' which is said to be contracting a looks like they just erased all of a except the four points where it crossed one of the other lines, and labelled the points with which line was crossed.

Comment: @coffeemath but the whole line a is still there

Comment: @JeanMarie I will edit my post, thank you.

Comment: @Intuition I agree whole line is there. So maybe it means keep only the line and the labelled points where it meets the other lines. This is why I say you need to go to your text and see what "contracting a" is defined to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a hyperplane arrangement $\mathcal{A}$ in dimension $d$, the contraction of $\mathcal{A}$ with respect to $H\in \mathcal{A}$ gives a new hyperplane arrangement in dimension $d-1$, defined as $\mathcal{A}/H=\{H\cap H':H'\in \mathcal{A}\}$. This can be viewed as a hyperplane arrangement in the space $H$, in which case we do not consider $H$ an element of $\mathcal{A}/H$ (note that this agrees with matroid contraction, where contracting an element removes it from the ground set). In the case depicted, $a$ just represents the space the arrangement is in, it is no longer considered an element (a hyperplane) of the arrangement $\mathcal{A}/H$.